# rails new and rails -v throwing this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is what happened when I  ran **rails -v** or **rails new**.  Haven't mucked around at all either.  I figured i'd post here before trashing the install and re-installing rails.

Assuming my install is shot

```
 /Users/fugazy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:112:in `require': /Users/fugazy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rails-0.13.1/lib/rails_generator/options.rb:124: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting '|' (SyntaxError)
    ...make any changes.') { |options[:pretend]| }
    ...                               ^
    /Users/fugazy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rails-0.13.1/lib/rails_generator/options.rb:127: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting '|'
    ...ss normal output.') { |options[:quiet]| }
    ...                               ^
    /Users/fugazy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rails-0.13.1/lib/rails_generator/options.rb:128: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting '|'
    ...ktrace on errors.') { |options[:backtrace]| }
    ...                               ^
    /Users/fugazy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rails-0.13.1/lib/rails_generator/options.rb:129: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting '|'
    ...his help message.') { |options[:help]| }
    ...                               ^
      from /Users/fugazy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:112:in `require'
      from /Users/fugazy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rails-0.13.1/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
      from /Users/fugazy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:112:in `require'
      from /Users/fugazy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:112:in `require'
      from /Users/fugazy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rails-0.13.1/lib/rails_generator.rb:34:in `<top (required)>'
      from /Users/fugazy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:112:in `require'
      from /Users/fugazy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:112:in `require'
      from /Users/fugazy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rails-0.13.1/bin/rails:14:in `<top (required)>'
      from /Users/fugazy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/rails:19:in `load'
      from /Users/fugazy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/rails:19:in `<main>'
      from /Users/fugazy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
      from /Users/fugazy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Comment: rails version 0.13.1 ?? What about a little update ? :)

Comment: didn't have rails in that directory lol.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My buddy didn't have rails in that directory, I fixed that.  Didn't realize it until @benjamin Sinclaire pointed out the versions #.